# Foreign Key constraints not copying into testdb during rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rake

Here is one issue which I am unable to debug. While doing an rake `db:test:clone_structure`, the foreign keys that are not copied from development database to test database. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: @mu yes even check constraints and triggers are left out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Rails (or ActiveRecord) doesn't understand foreign keys inside the database, nor does it understand CHECK constraints or anything else fancier than a unique index. Rails is generally nice to work with but sometimes there is more attitude than good sense in Rails.

There is [Foreigner](https://github.com/sparkfly/foreigner) for adding FK support to ActiveRecord but that doesn't know about Oracle. You might be able to adapt the PostgreSQL support to Oracle but I don't know my way around Oracle so that might not be a good idea. Foreigner also doesn't support CHECK constraints (yet).

The quick solution would be to dump the FKs and CHECKs as raw SQL and pump that SQL into your test and production databases. Then wrap a quick script around that that does a `rake db:test:clone_structure` followed by the raw SQL FK and CHECK copying.

Sorry that there's no easy way to do this but once you get outside the bounds of what a framework wants to do things get ugly (and the more comprehensive the framework, the uglier things get). A little bit of SQL wrangling wrapped around the usual rake command isn't that nasty though.